# Oracle APEX(v21.1.2): DatePicker inconsistent

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I'm on Apex Version: 21.1.2

I'm facing a weird issue with an Item(P2_Invoice_From_Date) of type DatePicker.
The Item is formated to display the selected date as ‘DD-MON-YYYY’ in the appearance section.
This is working as expected if user picks the date from the date picker pop-up.
If user tried to provide the date manually eg: for 25-Jan-2024 as 25/01/24 then it is working as expected displaying as ‘25-Jan-2024’, but if the user enters the date as ‘10/01/24’ for 10-Jan-2024, it is displayed as ‘01-Oct-2024’.

It was observed that if user enters first two values(date) less than 12 then the system is considering the date as month and if the first two values(date) are greater than 12 then ApEx considers it as Date only.

I verified 'Application Date Format" in Globalization tab of “Edit Application Properties”, it is set to DD-MON-YYYY.

Let me know if you need any further info from my end.

Anyone faced this issue and have a solution?
Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks

Naga

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the format mask to this specific page item too.

Select date picker page item, under `Appearance > Format Mask` > add `DD-MON-YYYY`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Yeyene.. Formating to DD/MM/YYYY solves the issue partially. 10/01/2024 is staying as it is and not changing as '01-Oct-2024'. But business needs the date format to be '01-Jan-2024'.

Comment: You are better off with setting the item readonly (Advanced > Custom Attributes > readonly) because if user is allowed to enter whatever they want, you will have to handle all these characters, non-leading zero date or month, etc.